# PHP Redirect with query parameters

Tags: php, redirect

Let's say I have the following URL:

```
http://example.com/index.php?user/1234
```

What I want the PHP query to do is redirect the user to the following URL:

```
http://example.com/test/index.php?user/1234
```

Of course, the URL should not only redirect `?user/1234` but also `?anything/343`. I want to leave the url intact and only add the `/test/` to it, and leave the part afterwards the same.

How do I accomplish that? All I could find is just general redirection and not specific to URLs. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to your question.

Comment: Why not? The accepted answer isn't 100% correct for my original case. Where should I post it otherwise?

Comment: As an actual answer to this question, OldMcDonald.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified Kasia Gogolek's answer so that it works for me. This is the solution to my question:

```
$fullUrl = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
// split the url
$url = parse_url($fullUrl);
$url['path'] = "/test" . $url['path'];
// create the new url with test in the path
$newUrl = $url['path']."?".$url['query'];
header("Location:" .$newUrl);
```

Comment: Thank you. On Stack Overflow, Questions and answers are meant to be kept separate :-)

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to parse your URL string and add 'test' to the path. The code below should do just that:

```
// $fullUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']."://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$fullUrl = "http://example.com/index.php?user/1234";
// split the url
$url = parse_url($fullUrl);
$url['path'] = "/test" . $url['path'];
// create the new url with test in the path
$newUrl = $url['scheme'] . "://".$url['host'].$url['path']."?".$url['query'];
header("Location:" .$newUrl);
```

Comment: Yes, you understood that correctly. The code isn't working quite correctly however. I get `http://example.com/:///test_://example.com/index.phpuser/1234/` as the URL. So it has some wrong `\` symbols, it's missing the `?` character and I get the domain name twice.

Comment: I forgot the question mark between path and query other than that it works for me.

Comment: Weird, I get the following `http://example.com/:///test://example.com/index.php?user/1234`. So it's some strange stuff with `://` and the fact that it doesn't remove the second `example.com`

Comment: what is the values for your: $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']
$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]
$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
?

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. Thank you for your help. I posted my edit in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP `header('location: url')` [as here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

URL being your intended new destination.

Comment: I don't know the new destination, it's dependent on the query

Comment: Could you be more specific? What would be different each time, the `test` part of the URL?

Comment: No, `test` would stay the same. Only the part afterwards should change. So for example, `example.com/index.php?whatever` should become `example.com/test/index.php?whatever`

Comment: You'd capture that, and append it to the new built URL. Kasia Gogolek's answer explains more.

Answer (score -1):

Should be a simple header redirect

```
header("Location:http://example.com/test/index.php?user/1234");
```

If the relocation is dependant on the query, then you need to build the location url.

For example, if you 2 variables on your page you want to use, 1 that is `$page` and one that is `$id`, you would do it like this.

```
 $id = 123;
 $page = 'user';

 header("Location:http://example.com/test/index.php?".$page."/".$id);
```

This would produce a url of

```
http://example.com/test/index.php?user/123
```

Comment: Yes, but what would I do if the URL doesn't have "?user/1234" but instead "?help/343"

Comment: Then you would change it to `header("Location:http://example.com/test/index.php?help/343");`

Comment: @OldMcDonald please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @OldMcDonald don't write it static, write it dynamic by putting your URL into a variable. Btw that URL format seems to be really weird...

Comment: I made my post clearer now. I want to add the `/test/` part to the URL and leave everything afterwards the same.